# Custom User Agent string in IIS SharePoint

Tags: iis, http-headers, httprequest, user-agent

Can we set a custom user agent string for a site in SharePoint or IIS? I see in IE Emulator we are able to set the user agent string and that is being used for all request we send. Can we do that programatically so that end user will get that custom user agent, not necessary to use emulator. My Site not working correct when I use IE in compatibility mode, so setting a custom user agent string does the trick

Answer (score 0):

You could set the custom user agent in iis by using URL rewrite rule:

Install URL rewrite from the below link:

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

1)open iis, select your SharePoint site.

2)double click on URL rewrite rule from middle pane:

[image]

3)click the View Server Variables link from the Actions pane on the right. From here we need to add HTTP_USER_AGENT into the list of Allowed Server Variables by clicking Add in the Actions pane.

[image]

[image]

4)When this step is complete, click the Back to Rules button from the Actions pane then press Add Rules(s). Select Blank rule under the Inbound rules section (the first selection on the top left) and enter/choose the following values:

Name: This rule can be named anything you wish for it to be named

[image]

Requested URL: Matches the Pattern

Using: Regular Expressions

Pattern: .*

[image]

**Conditions**:

Logical grouping: Match All

Click Add Condition and then enter the following data:

Condition input: {HTTP_USER_AGENT}

Check if input string: Matches the Pattern

Pattern: .*Trident/([7-9]|0*[1-9]\d+).*(rv:1[1-9]).*

Note: set the pattern as per your requirement.

**Server Variables**:

Click Add and then enter the following data:

Server variable name: HTTP_USER_AGENT

Value: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)

Replace the existing value: Checked

Action

Action type: None

after adding this value apply the rule.